# How to store database credentials in Google App Engine Standard?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, django, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-standard

I'm experimenting with hosting a Django application on Google App Engine Standard and to do that I followed the tutorial [Running Django on App Engine Standard Environment](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine). That tutorial completely ignores the problem of safely handling credentials (and it sorts of points to just storing them in your code repo... *sigh*).

When searching for how to store credentials there's a lot of articles about Google Cloud Key Management Service, but I don't really need that. I'm ok with the credentials being stored at GCP unencrypted (it's for the GCP database anyway). What I need is a way for my application to pick up that configuration automatically.

My app can either get environment variables or a `.env` file that contains this information. How do I get the credentials and other configs to be present like that in my Google App Engine Standard instance?

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this has driven me nuts for a while, but I finally have the answer.  It uses Memcached, so it's fast in production.

1. In GCP, go to APIs & Services, and enable the Google Datastore API.
2. Then setup a Service Account and authenticate according to this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
3. In your local envrionment, `pip install google-cloud-datastore`.
4. Then you'll want to create a module in the same folder as `settings.py` called something like `datastore.py`:

Here is my `datastore.py`:

```
from google.cloud import datastore
from django.core.cache import cache


class DataStoreClient():
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = datastore.Client()

    def get(self, property):
        try:
            cache_key = 'env-' + property
            result = cache.get(cache_key)

            if not result:
                key = self.client.key('environment_variables', property)
                result = self.client.get(key)
                cache.set(cache_key, result, 86400)

            return result['Value']

        except TypeError:
            print(
                "{} is not a property in Cloud Datastore".format(property) +
                "We are creating one for you.  Go to Cloud Datastore to set a value."
            )
            entity = datastore.Entity(key=key)
            entity.update({
                'Value': 'NOT_SET'}
            )
            self.client.put(entity)
```

Then in the settings, you just call for keys like this:

```
from your_app.datastore import DataStoreClient

datastore_client = DataStoreClient()

SECRET_KEY = datastore_client.get('SECRET_KEY')
```

When you run `python manage.py runserver` for the first time, the system will populate `NOT_SET` values in Google DataStore.  From here, you can go to GCP and change those keys on datastore.

This solution is nice in that, once there is a value, it will retrieve it for you.

If you really want to get crazy (as I have), you could set up a script that includes all your environment variables locally, encrypts them with KMS, uploads them, then write the DataStoreClient to only download and decrypt.